# Core Service API : Does it contain Tridion Constants values

Tags: core-service, api

I'm looking around the Core Service API for an Enum that contains Tridion constants such as `http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0` for the NameSpace Uri, does such information exist in there?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I didn't find tridion constants in Core Service DLL but I'm using `Tridion.Common.dll` for all the Tridion Constants

### Example:

```
Tridion.Constants.TcmNamespace
Tridion.Constants.XlinkNamespace
```

Comment: thanks siva, yeah i'm aware of them being in the common dll but i wondered if they were also part of the core service.

Comment: @johnwinter: As far as I know, we don't have constants in core service.